# $p$-th root of $\varpi$ in a perfectoid field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be a perfectoid field, i.e. a complete nonarchimedean field $K$ with non-discrete rank 1 value groups and characteristic $p$ residue field, such that the p-th power frobenius map $O_K/p \to O_K/p$ is surjective.

A paper I am reading says one can always find $\varpi \in O_K$ with $|p|\leq |\varpi|<1$ and $p$th-root $\varpi^{1/p} \in O_K$. Why? I think it should follow easily  the fact the value group is not discrete, but I'm being stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from Lemma 3.2 in Scholze's Perfectoid Spaces paper, which says the value group of a perfectoid field is $p$-divisible.

Here is how the proof goes. Since the valuation is not discrete, the value group is not $|p|^\mathbb{Z}$, so there is $x \in K$ such that $|p|<|x|<1=|p|^0$. Then since Frobenius $O_K/p \to O_K/p$ is surjective, there exists $y \in O_K$, such that $y^p-x \in pO_K$, i.e. $|y^p -x|\leq |p|$. Then $|y^p| \leq \max\{|y^p-x|, |x|\}=|p|$ and we have $|y|^p=|p|$. Set $\varpi^{1/p}=y$.